# MQTT messages not published from ESP32 to AWS IoT Core

Tags: arduino, mqtt, esp32, aws-iot, aws-iot-core

I am trying to publish data to AWS IoT Core through MQTT. I am following this [tutorial](https://how2electronics.com/connecting-esp32-to-amazon-aws-iot-core-using-mqtt/) and have followed all steps but the messages are not coming through to the MQTT test client when subscribing to any of the topics 'esp32/pub' or 'esp32/sub'. This is the JSON of the policy in AWS IoT:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Condition": {
        "Bool": {
          "iot:Connection.Thing.IsAttached": "true"
        }
      },
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:Connect",
      "Resource": "{ARN}:client/ESP32_SNSR_0"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:Publish",
      "Resource": "{ARN}:topic/esp32/pub"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:Subscribe",
      "Resource": "{ARN}:topicFilter/esp32/sub"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:Receive",
      "Resource": "{ARN}:topic/esp32/sub"
    }
  ]
}
```

I used the ARN that came from one of the rules generated from policy examples. I have changed the policy to allow all access and now I can publish and subscribe. How can I adjust these policies to get more restrictive?

Answer (score 0):

I was also having trouble with publishing messages to AWS IoT Core. A few steps that helped me:

1. Use the AWS MQTT test client to make sure your messages are coming through. If they are not, create a rule that will use an Amazon CloudWatch log; this can help you track errors and find the source of the issue.
2. For making your policies more restrictive, ChatGPT can help you do so. Just make sure you are giving it enough information to generate the JSON code for the policy.
3. The Arduino MQTT library can be a little difficult to work with. You can try publishing messages to your serial monitor in Arduino IDE, reading these messages from the serial monitor in Python (pyserial module), then establishing an MQTT communication from there (AWSIoTMQTTClient module).